# C# console attempts to override the app.config value for the Default Database used by DatabaseFactory doesn't keep the change..CreateDatabase()

Tags: c#, overriding, app-config, default-database

I need to override the DefaultDatabase value in the app.config used by `DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase() of DAAB`

I have the code below, and it indicates the change succeeds, but when I reference the default database later in the code, it no longer has the changes saved by the code below.
This happens whether in debug mode or as a compiled exe.

```
Database db = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase();
```

code to change the app.config

```
        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
            var dbSettings = (DatabaseSettings)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("dataConfiguration");

        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbSettings.DefaultDatabase].ConnectionString;

        connectionString = connectionString.Replace("DATABASETOREPLACE", dstuff.Database).Replace("SERVERTOREPLACE", dstuff.Server);

        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[dbSettings.DefaultDatabase].ConnectionString = connectionString;

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified, true);
        ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");
```

app.config values

Comment: Are you running your application from Visual studio?

Comment: no, it is compiled and running as a standalone exe

Answer (score 0):

Try `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("configuration");`
instead of `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");`

Comment: nope.  Now when I execute this line of code: string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[dbSettings.DefaultDatabase].ConnectionString;
I get a connectionstring with an empty DataSource and an empty Initial_Catalog.   the userid and password are correct